# HTML5 Video - controls are not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I was asked to fix some bugs for an "online magazine app" which was written almost completely in JS&Python.

And I've faced quite a strange bug. On some pages controls for an usual HTML5 video tag doesn't work. So pause&fullscreen buttons just cannot be clicked. And on some other pages controls work just fine.

So example of a page, where video controls doesn't seem to work:
http://layergloss.com/webapp/24/24/Code-R.html#/page/26

Example of a page, where everything works just fine:
http://layergloss.com/webapp/24/24/Code-R.html#/page/6

P. S. Bonus question:
How would you optimize the app in a fast way? Any ideas?
Do you think that it's possible to make the app faster by rewriting it (for example) in AngularJS? Because now it seems to load almost the whole magazine and that doesn't really work fast...

Comment: Neither of those pages loads for me, at least not within two minutes.

Comment: hmmm... Try to load it starting from the first page:
http://layergloss.com/webapp/24/24/

Comment: Quite mysterious, good luck figuring it out. I can only suggest the classical debugging technique of gradually removing things until you figure out what is causing the issue.